# How to sort part of a data frame by multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

Sorting has been discussed quite a bit here, but I have a particular problem. I have a data frame (df) with several columns. All the observations belong to one of three types, say C1, C2, and C3. Of the various columns, one contains a value which I will call frequency (f). Example df:

```
  Type  freq  Val 
   C3.   0.34.  10-A
   C1.   0.90.  4-A
   C2.   0.40.  5-B
   C1.   0.65.  3-C
   C2.   0.77.  5-D
   C3.   0.11.  5-D
```

I need to sort this table so that the primary key is the Type, and secondary key is the frequency. However, and here’s my problem, they need to be sorted by a particular order of type. I need them by C1, C3, C2. So the final table looks like this:

```
   Type  freq  Val
   C1.   0.90.  4-A
   C1.   0.65.  3-C
   C3.   0.34.  10-A
   C3.   0.11.  5-D
   C2.   0.77.  5-D
   C2.   0.40.  5-B
```

Is there a way to do this? To pick the particular ordering scheme of the column Type. Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the 'Type' to `factor` with `levels` specified in the custom order

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   arrange(factor(Type, levels = c('C1.', 'C3.', 'C2.')), desc(freq))
#  Type  freq  Val
#1  C1. 0.90.  4-A
#2  C1. 0.65.  3-C
#3  C3. 0.34. 10-A
#4  C3. 0.11.  5-D
#5  C2. 0.77.  5-D
#6  C2. 0.40.  5-B
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Type := factor(Type,  levels = c('C1.', 'C3.', 'C2.'))]
setorder(df1, Type, -freq)
```

---

In `base R`, we can do

```
df1[order(factor(df1$Type, levels = c('C1.', 'C3.', 'C2.')), -df1$freq),]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Type = c("C3.", "C1.", "C2.", "C1.", "C2.", "C3."
), freq = c("0.34.", "0.90.", "0.40.", "0.65.", "0.77.", "0.11."
), Val = c("10-A", "4-A", "5-B", "3-C", "5-D", "5-D")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: I’m working with the “dplyr” library. My final df is arranging freq correctly, but the order of the Type is yielding C1, C2, C3, and not C1, C3, C2. I wonder if there’s something missing.

Comment: @Orion11 If you neeed to change the column, assign the `factor` output to that column and then it should work

Comment: Ok. I got it to work.  I was missing the "$Type" part.  Thank you very much.